# How to add bootstrap-5.3.3 support for Flask-Admin

Tags: python, flask, bootstrap-5, flask-admin

I am learning to create MVC architecture web applications. I find Flask the perfect choice for this because of the easy syntax of Python and full control over the app because of the minimalism of the framework.

Recently I wanted to create an admin panel for one of my recent projects. I found Flask-Admin the best fit for me. The only problem I am facing currently is that **I am unable to find any guide, repository, or piece of documentation that can guide me on how to add bootstrap-5.3.3 support for flask-admin.**

So I took the matter into my own hands and started to look at the source of flask-admin and added the bootstrap5 directory at static, copy-pasted bootstrap4 templates to bootstrap5 templates but I don't think it changed anything.

**Anyway, I think at this point I don't have any time, knowledge, and money to add bootstrap5 support to flask-admin.**

I can surly do it by myself if there is a proper guide for how to do that.
Thanks for reading.